# How to assign Ctrl+/ as a KeyGesture in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to assign a shortcut to powershell ISE using this line of code

```
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("Comment Selected Lines",{Comment-IseSelectedLines},"Ctrl+/")
```

---

But I got this error

```
Cannot convert argument "shortcut", with value: "Ctrl+/", for "Add" to type
"System.Windows.Input.KeyGesture": "Cannot convert value "Ctrl+/" to type 
"System.Windows.Input.KeyGesture". Error: "Requested value '/' was not found.""
```

---

If i change <kbd>/</kbd> to other letter, say <kbd>O</kbd>, the error goes away.
So is there anyway I can use <kbd>/</kbd>?

---

This is the code I ended up using

```
#Ctrl + /
$KeyGesture = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Input.KeyGesture -ArgumentList ([System.Windows.Input.Key]::OemQuestion, [System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys]::Control);
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("Comment Selected Lines",{Comment-IseSelectedLines},$KeyGesture)

#ctrl + Shift + /
$KeyGesture = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Input.KeyGesture -ArgumentList ([System.Windows.Input.Key]::OemQuestion, 6)
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("Uncomment Selected Lines",{Uncomment-IseSelectedLines},$KeyGesture)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to research it:

1. Look up the `System.Windows.Input.KeyGesture` class; e.g.: http://www.google.com/search?&q=System.Windows.Input.KeyGesture
2. You can see that the `KeyGesture` class has a member called `Key`, which is an enumeration that is a list of available keys: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key.aspx
3. Look in the list of keys for the `/` key. It's not in there, but there is a `Divide` and an `OemQuestion`.

I tried with `Ctrl+OemQuestion` and it works with both the `/`/`?` key and the `/` key on the numeric keypad.